# IBM Watson Text Translator example syntactically wrong. How to auto detect language

Tags: java, ibm-watson, language-translation

As per the [Translator API reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/language-translator/api/v2/?java#identifiable_languages), to identify language use below code:

```
LanguageTranslator service = new LanguageTranslator();
service.setUsernameAndPassword("{username}","{password}");

List <IdentifiedLanguage> langs = service.identify("this is a test");
System.out.println(langs);
```

But as one can see in the attached screenshot that results into syntatic error. I have corrected that by just changing one line as :

```
ServiceCall<List<IdentifiedLanguage>> langs = service.identify("this is a test");
```

It would be great if documentation can be updated. 
Error is gone but now what to do with this ServiceCall? How to get language?

Also any link giving all model Ids would be appreciated as that helps during initial evaluation of API. Also where can I find which languages are supported currently?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Simply comment that line as I don't see local variable "*langs*" being used anywhere further in the method.
2. In case you need it make a call to execute method on service.identify("this is a test") and then initialize it to variable "*langs*" something like below:

   List langs = service.identify("this is a test").execute();

Answer (score 1):

The `service.identify("...")` call needs a `.execute()`, not a different type:

```
List<IdentifiedLanguage> langs = service.identify("this is a test").execute();
```

It then returns the expected list of IdentifiedLanguages. Here's a complete example that logs the list and then chooses the highest-confidence language from the list and logs that also:

```
package com.watson.example;

import java.util.Collections;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.language_translator.v2.LanguageTranslator;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.language_translator.v2.model.IdentifiedLanguage;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class ItentifyLanguage {
    public ItentifyLanguage() {
        LanguageTranslator service = new LanguageTranslator();
        service.setUsernameAndPassword("{username}","{password}");

        // identify returns a list of potential languages with confidence scores
        List<IdentifiedLanguage> langs = service.identify("this is a test").execute();
        System.out.println("language confidence scores:");
        System.out.println(langs);

        // this narrows the list down to a single language
        IdentifiedLanguage lang = Collections.max(langs, new Comparator<IdentifiedLanguage>() {
            public int compare (IdentifiedLanguage a, IdentifiedLanguage b) {
                return a.getConfidence().compareTo(b.getConfidence());
            }
        });

        System.out.println("Language " + lang.getLanguage() + " has the highest confidence score at " + lang.getConfidence());
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ItentifyLanguage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- For your question about which languages are supported, that's in the
  doc
  https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/language-translator/index.html#supported-languages
- I've notified the doc team about the syntax error.
- I am looking for an SME who can answer your technical questions